# What is the step-by-step procedure to fix the "The following packages have unmet dependencies"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt-get

I tried everything but made no progress. Can a smart soul help out?

Of course just `sudo apt-get -f install` does not work, same error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install arping
[sudo] password for dloo:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 arping : Depends: libnet1 (>= 1.1.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux li366-234 2.6.39.1-x86_64-linode19 #1 SMP Tue Jun 21 10:04:20 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu as that may give hints of why it is not working?

Comment: Check my last edit

Comment: Any chance of upgrading your Ubuntu? 11 is out of support by now I think..

Comment: Any chance of upgrading your Ubuntu as per https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=arping it is not supported in that version of Ubuntu. Gluonman answer is your best bet short of upgrading.

Answer (score 12):

I have no idea if it is still relevant for you to get help on this, but here is a summary of the things one could do to help in such situation
(from [here at Appuals (appuals.com)](https://appuals.com/fix-unmet-dependencies-error-ubuntu/)) :

Method 1: Use the `-f` parameter (I know you already did that, but I gather everything here altogether)

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Method 2: Use Aptitude

```
sudo aptitude install PACKAGENAME
```

where *`PACKAGENAME`* is the package you’re installing,
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it. This will try to install the package via aptitude instead of apt-get, which should potentially fix the unmet dependencies issue.

Method 3: Make sure that the restricted and universe repositories are enabled and try a better server

```
software-properties-gtk
```

- In the Ubuntu Software tab, make sure that all the repositories (main, universe, restricted, multiverse) are enabled.
- Click the list of servers where it says “Download from”, and choose
- Click “Select Best Server”.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> simultaneously to open a Terminal, and type in

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  then press

  Once it’s done running, try installing the software again.

Method 4: Clean the package database

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Method 5: Eliminate any held packages

```
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

then (if pb):

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
```

and see if it fixes the issue. If it exits with `X not upgraded` at the end, where *`X`* is the number of held packages, you will need to delete them one by one.

To remove a held package,

```
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run PACKAGENAME
```

(*`PACKAGENAME`* is the package you’re trying to remove). The `--dry-run` parameter makes sure you are informed of whatever happens next. When you’ve removed all packages, try installing the one that caused the problem in the first place, and see what happens.

Method 6: Purge/Remove/Disable PPAs

Personal Package Archives are repositories that are hosted on the Launchpad, and are used to upgrade or install packages that aren’t usually available in the official repositories of Ubuntu. They’re most commonly a cause of unmet dependencies, especially when they’re used to upgrade an existing package from the Ubuntu repository. You can either disable, remove or purge them.

Then if they still show some dependency issues, let's purge them:

```
apt purge packageXX packageYY packageZZ
```

etc.
until everything is clean

Some say also to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and remove blocs which have not complete installation but I doubt this really solves problems, it is just hiding it under the carpet.

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you try the following?

   ```
   apt-get check
   ```
2. Try first:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but both 1 and 2 gave me the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the information on Ubuntu's wiki (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) reached end-of-life on October 28, 2012.  Your specific error implies that the available version of arping depends on more updated versions of libraries that probably just aren't available in Natty Narwhal, or Natty Narwhal may simply refuse to build those libraries because they will introduce incompatibilities with the rest of your unsupported platform.

Your two options are to see if you can find the sources for the libraries that arping needs (keeping in mind to satisfy arping's version requirements), and see if you can have any success building them manually (e.g. the whole ./configure && make && sudo make install routine).  But I can't guarantee that that will work, and again, your OS is unsupported.  Alternatively, backup all your desired data, download a copy of Ubuntu 17.10.1 (or 16.04.3 if you prefer to stick with LTS) and make a bootable USB and install an updated, currently supported version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple if you read the error.

Suppose the package you're trying to install is **packageA**.

Trying to install **packageA** will lead you to something like this:

```
packageA: Depends: packageX (>= a.b) but it is not going to be installed
```

You need to run `sudo apt-get install packageX`.

Likely you will have another error which says:

```
packageX: Depends: packageY (>= a.b) but it is not going to be installed
```

Run `sudo apt-get install packageY` to install it.

Keep going like this (IMO most packages have a tree 3-4 nodes deep), until you install the last dependency in the series.

After that, your first command to install **packageA** will run successfully.